# Is it possible to see an entire window title?

Tags: windows, windows-10, process, title

While surfing to a site within my company, the browser's title seems to be an error message.

In the taskbar, I can see the following:

```
TF400813: The user 'e387ba6a-0...
```

While using `tasklist /V | findstr "TF"`, I can see the following:

```
TF400813: The user 'e387ba6a-09a6-4c12-8c76-6492ea8f582d\dominique.xxxxx
```

(I've blurred the letters of my family name for privacy reasons, but I can tell you that only five letters are shown, there seems to be a maximum of 72 characters.)

You can clearly see that not the entire error message is visible.

Does anybody know how (if possible) I can see the full window title?

My operating system is Windows-10.

**Edit after some more investigation**
The following PowerShell command doesn't work:

```
Get-Process | format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle -AutoSize
```

Most probably because the mentioned browser window is just one of several browser windows, and the `Powershell` command only shows the title of the **main**window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you mean by `"the mentioned browser window is just one of several browser windows"` ? can you elaborate a little and tell us which browser did you mean by ?

Comment: I'm working with Google Chrome, and apparently you can have different browser windows under the same process ID. When trying to find the title using the Powershell command, I just get one single result for that process ID, and it's not the one with that particular large title. When I close the window, shown in Powershell, I just get a default title, not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the browsers Inspect/Debug feature to look at the HTML of the page and find the title?

Comment: you can always use *khalifa* *attwood* as dummy names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
tasklist /fi "WindowTitle eq TF*" /v /fo list

tasklist /fi "WindowTitle eq TF*" /v /fo csv

tasklist /fi "WindowTitle eq TF*" /v /fo list | find /i "TF"
```

Comment: The `/fo list` switch does it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Frame challenge: Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in the browser to open the dev tools. The full contents of the title tag will be visible in the head section of the inspection pane.

Comment: …or even just `Ctrl`+`U`. The `<title>` element is rarely filled dynamically, and usually is amongst the first lines of the html.

Comment: If you're using the browser Dev Tools, then it would be better to type `console.log(document.title);`, as that would display the title, even if it was dynamically set. Looking for a `<title>` in the `<head>` doesn't cover any time that it's set dynamically.

Comment: In Chrome, `ctrl-u` shows the source. If you need access to the console, it is `ctrl+shift+i`. From there, you don't even need `console.log`. Just typing in `document.title` will resolve the DOM and show you its content.

Comment: @Makyen setting the `document.title` will go as far as creating the `<title>` element, and as little as setting its text content. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#document.title

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, but if the HTML has more than one `<title>` element, then you're not guaranteed to find the one which the browser is actually using. Sure, there's not *supposed* to be more than one `<title>` element, but that isn't something which is guaranteed. I'd prefer to do a little more typing than spend time looking for something in the HTML, which *might* not be the thing I'm actually looking for.

Comment: @Makyen it is guaranteed to be the first.

Comment: @Kaiido Unless it has been dynamically been changed by a script somewhere else.

Comment: @Nelson no. That's my point, it's **always** the text content of the first <title> element in the DOM, or the empty string in case there is no such <title> element. The getter steps of `document.title` is precisely to return the text content of the first title element in the DOM or `""`. So, no, dynamically setting the document's title won't change this fact. That someone prefers to type `document.title` in the console rather than checking the DOM's rendered markup is a personal preference, mine is to hover the tab I want to check the title of, but that's just a preference.

Comment: @Kaiido What you're saying is wrong, and easily tested. The `document.title` returns the browser's current title, whether it is set by the first title tag or by `document.title = "string"`. You can go on to any page, change the title via `document.title = ` and then immediately retrieve it. I'm not sure why you think otherwise.

Comment: @Nelson you probably have issues understanding what I said... Please read again all my comments here. When you do `document.title = "foo"` what happens is that the browser will search for the first <title> in the DOM, if there isn't one, it will create one and append it in the <head>, and then it will set the text content of this first <title> to the string `foo`. So "Looking for a <title> in the <head>" DOES "cover any time that it's set dynamically.". Note that we are talking about the DOM view from Dev-tools, and obviously not about the markup from `source:`.

Comment: Ok, so you're referring to the GUI version of `document.title`, as presented by the Elements tab in the DOM viewer. We're basically talking about the same thing.

Comment: "the GUI version of document.title"? What's that? No I am saying that what @makyen said was wrong, that you can very well only look at the text content of the first <title> in the DOM as proposed by this answer and you'll get the current document's title. I'm saying that if you do `document.title = "foo"; document.querySelector("title").textContent = "bar";` then `document.title` will return `"bar"`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this powershell script can answer or not your question for your case :

```
$ArrayBrowsers=@("firefox","chrome","iexplore","msedge","opera")
ForEach ($Browser in $ArrayBrowsers) {
    Get-Process $Browser -EA SilentlyContinue |
        Where mainwindowtitle -NE '' |
            select ID,name,mainwindowtitle | FT -AutoSize
}
```

Comment: Sorry for pulling back the "Accept", but the other answer, based on `Tasklist`, is more suited for my needs.